# Adobe Air: how to limit download speed?

Tags: apache-flex, air

Is there any possibility in Adobe AIR to control bandwidth usage with AIR when downloading a file using URLStream?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't.  It is not Air's purpose to 'limit' any kind of downloads (and I don't get why you would in the first place...) since if you're going over HTTP it actually uses the OS' default browser.

The only way you could limit it is by create a Socket and try to implement an HTTP protocol within that or implement your own protocol.  Frankly, I wouldn't even try.  I don't see much use for limiting bandwidth for download...

Comment: Limiting bandwidth is quite useful when you have slow connection. For example most of download managers and torrent clients do so. However the question is still open... Maybe i can simulate it by using timer or changing the buffer size?...

Comment: Yeah, but those are all native apps that can communicate with the hardware.  This is Air which is meant to have an abstraction layer to that kind of stuff.

Comment: The pertinent point here is that for the most part AIR doesn't do it's own network stack, it passes requests to the OS and lets you know when it gets a reply. If you load data yourself through a socket, you can control how much data you ask for at a time, but each chunk will still be transmitted as always.

Answer (score 0):

you can try and check if NetLimiter can handle this. Here is the link

http://www.netlimiter.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! NetLimiter seems to be native Windows application, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You are welcome! Maybe helpful too: (not me)
"URLStream is very similar to URLLoader, but instead of waiting for the file to completely download before using the result, data is made available to you during the download. This method works well for large files because you don't have to wait for the full download to start saving it to disk, and you also save on memory since once the player hands it off to you it can release the memory related to that data. YOu would use filestream in exactly the same way, you would just end up doing a writeBytes() on each chunk of the file as it streams in."

Comment: I wrote an AIR Downloader application which usign URLStream and FileStream to download and save files. The problem is that I can't figure out how I can limit downloading speed with AIR, because application "eats" all available traffic :(

Answer (score 0):

"eats all available traffic" is a good thing on the client side.

If a stream download speeds becomes slower then the time played the user will have to wait for buffering and this would be bad.

Your best bet is detect the speed of DL and if it lesser then XXX have it download a lower rez video. To do this you will need to have a few versions of the file on the server. This allows the client to get optimized speeds. You can also allow the user to override it To get HD quality if they really want to see high def

Comment: Another thing on the bandwidth detection thats good is you can be testing often and if speeds increase you can change the stream on the fly seamlessly